# Problems connecting to a remote database from a Java desktop application

Tags: java, mysql, webservice-client, mysql-connector

I have a desktop Java application, provided via Web Start, that I need to modify to add some authentication capabilities.  We have a MySQL database for our website that hosts the authentication details that I need to connect to in order to verify that the user has a current subscription to the software.  I understand it's not popular to be coding user authentication, but that's the framework I have to fit in to.

**Issue 1:**

So the first step was to try using the MySQL Connector/J to connect to the database, submit a query and process the result.  This works brilliantly in Eclipse, but as soon as it is built and run from the JNLP file outwith the IDE it doesn't work.  I get the following error in the console:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
```

the error is caught at the code below:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

I have configured the project build path in Eclipse to include the MySQl connector jar file, it is in the CLASSPATH environment variable, and it is included as an external jar in the JNLP configuration.  So I think I have covered all the usual bases, but still no luck.

**Issue 2:**

To get around issue 1, I decided to create a web service in PHP using nuSoap and consuming that service from within my application.  Building the web service was straightforward, but figuring out how to consume it in my application is turning out to be much more difficult.  Bearing in mind that I don't have anything like tomcat or glassfish, I'm struggling to figure out exactly how to submit a value to the web service and handle a response.  It's a very simple web service - it submits a user ID, and gets a return value to indicate whether the user has a valid subscription.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated, even if it's a better method of getting the result I need!!

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: Do you use the executables (jars or whatever) built by eclipse? Check whether if the mysql jar is in your jar or not.

Comment: It's not included within the applications jar file, as it comes as a pre-built jar that I've referenced.  The application references other jar files and they work ok, so I presumed that this one would work in the same way.  All the jar files (both referenced and built by Eclipse) are in the correct paths relative to the JNLP file.

Comment: Did you place the mysql JAR in the same folder as the main jar, and is it accessible via the web?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same folder as the main jar.  For testing I'm running this on my desktop not on the website.

Comment: I think you should check the classpaths for the 'java' command you use for starting the application. The current directory is not on the path by default, you have to specify it. (If this is a wrong cp problem we have to know the directory structure and the cp argument exaclty, to give and exact answer)